# PHPmailer - Add pdf file as attachment doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, phpmailer

**My Goal:**

Use `AddStringAttachment()` to send a auto-generated base64 string as a `.pdf` file to another email address.

**Coding Environment:**

I'm working on WordPress with a ajax call passing a base64 string to the server. The size of the string is usually around 30kbs, it can be guaranteed not exceeding over 50kbs. I have `MAX_EXECUTION_TIME` 120s.

**What I've Been Working Through:**

I succeeded:

- Sending plain text body
- Sending a small `.txt` file

I failed:

- Sending base64 string using `AddStringAttachment()`. The server returns me a [504 Gateway Time-out](http://#) error most of time, even if `$mail->send()` function passes through, I can only receive a corrupt `.pdf` file with 10kbs bigger than original size.
- Sending a already exist `.pdf` file with `AddAttachment()`, The server also returns me a [504 Gateway Time-out](http://#) error, and I also get a warning like [Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf](http://#)

**My Code:**

```
function sendPdf() {

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';                   // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'janice@popper.ga';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                         // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipient
    $mail->SetFrom('janice@popper.ga');
    $mail->AddAddress( 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com' );

    $pdf_base64 = $_POST[pdfString];

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject= ' New Application Form ';
    $mail->Body= ' New Application Form From WordPress site ';

    //Attachment
    //$mail->AddStringAttachment($pdf_base64, $_POST[clientName].'_Application.pdf', 'base64', 'application/pdf');
    //$mail->AddAttachment(dirname(__FILE__)."/Qian_Zhong_Application.pdf", 'Qian_Zhong_Application.pdf');

    $error = '';

    if(!$mail->send()){
       $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
       echo $error;     
    }else{
        echo 'Message has been sent.';
    }

    exit; // This is required to end AJAX requests properly.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you pass in to `addStringAttachment` should be raw binary, not encoded in any way, as PHPMailer will take care of that for you. It will also set the encoding and MIME type from the filename you provide, so you do not need to set them manually.

Using a debugger would allow you to watch the script as it runs so you would be able to see exactly what it’s having trouble with. Any error 500s will cause errors to be logged in your web server logs and will usually provide more info.

I would also recommend against using `$_POST[clientName]` like that without any filtering or validation - you should never trust user input like that.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've solved the problem already. You are right, I found out the first parameter in `addStringAttachment` should be binary. About the 504 error, I've transferred the server location, then the problem was solved. Can you give me some ideas of filtering or validating the user input?

Comment: If you want `clientName` to contain only readable text, filter for that to avoid getting things like line breaks, other control characters, leading & trailing spaces, for example: `$clientName = trim(preg_replace('/[^\w ]/', '', $_POST['clientName']));`

Comment: 'raw binary' was the keyword for me. I've been sending an encoded string to file_get_contents.